# CMake, add_subdirectory и наследование окружения

Tags: android, c++, ios, cmake, кросс-компиляция

Делаю проект с компиляцией под несколько платформ на `c++`. Некоторые файлы нужно прогнать утилитой (для простоты понимания скажем, что это транспилятор). Этот транспилятор нужно собрать из исходников, для него уже настроен `CMakeLists.txt`.

Подключаю его так:

```
add_subdirectory(my/transpilator)
```

Ну и добавляю таргет:

```
add_custom_target(transpile ALL COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -D... 
            -DTRANSPILER_EXECUTABLE=$<TARGET_FILE:my_transpiler> -P transpile_all.cmake)
```

Подключаю его как зависимость к главному таргету и при сборке `transpile_all.cmake` транспилирует нужные файлы.

Проблема же возникает на платформах вроде `Android` или `IOS`. Так как для них нужно настраивать специфическое окружение, флаги компилятора, архитектуру и прочее, очевидно, что при подключении проекта транспилятора через `add_subdirectory` он унаследует все эти настройки. Окружение же настраивается тулчейном и добавить `add_subdirectory` перед настройкой окружения я не могу.

На данный момент думаю использовать "костыльное" решение - запускать `cmake` для транспилятора во время конфигурации и компилировать его. Что-то вроде:

```
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -Htranspiler/folder -Btranspiler/output)
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build transpiler/folder ...)
```

Потом там экспортировать какую-нибудь переменную окружения и читать из нее путь до бинарника, чтобы передать в `transpile_all.cmake`.

В правильном ли я направлении думаю, или же есть какой-то способ, скажем, сделать `add_subdirectory`, но без наследования настроек окружения, или что-то подобное?

Comment: А почему бы не добавить настройки, которые может видеть только транспилятор? Всмысле в его cmake файле (или типа того). Таким образом те спецефичные настройки, которые вы зададите будут по прежнему доступны из кэша, но для транспилятора будут использоваться локальные.

Comment: Можно также добавить некую переменную согласно которой для компиляции транспилятора будут браться данные либо из кэша, либо те, которые доступны локально

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch дело в том, что настраивается достаточно много всего. А я не хочу изменив что-то в коде тулчейна лезть и менять что-то ещё и для проекта. А локальные я настройки использую в некоторой мере, но то, что мне нужно, уж проще через `execute_process` реализовать...

Comment: Так о почему бы не реализовать для вашего транслятора (cmake) полный набор настроек, которые бы никак не зависели от того, что устанавливаются из вне? Тобишь что бы вы там не настраивали, на транслятор бы это никак не влияло

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch да, попробую так сделать. Кажется, можно взять `CXXFLAGS` и рефрешнуть ими текущие флаги. Посмотрим, что выйдет

Comment: Да, только переменная называется CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS и, если вам не нужно получать настройки из кэша для этой переменной, то буде выглядеть просто как set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -g -andotherflags") без установки ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}. Также стоит помнить, что есть и DEBUG версия (не помню насчет других), так что ее тоже стоит переопределить. Ну и другие настройки которые не должны меняться.